# 最好还是问问老师吧？还是最好问问老师吧？ Which is correct? and Why is it?

Tags: grammar

这个问题，最好还是问问老师吧.

这个问题，还是最好问问老师吧.

It means "Sure enough, the best is that we ask teacher about this problem."

Which is correct? and Why?

Both of them go well?

Comment: user suggestion: submit both of 最好还是 and  还是最好 to iciba, get exactly 7 examples for either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either "这个问题，最好(it is the best to/ better)问问老师吧" or "这个问题，还是(better off) 问问老师吧" would be more efficient

In "这个问题，**最好还是**问问老师吧" or "这个问题，**还是最好**问问老师吧" 最好 or 还是 are redundant if you use 还是 as "better off" in the context

But 还是 could also mean "is still"

> 1. 这个问题(about this question)，最好(the best *thing to do* )还是(is still)问问老师吧 (ask the teacher)
> 2. 这个问题(about this question)，还是(it is still) 最好(best to))问问老师吧 (ask the teacher)

Both would make sense, It implies there are other options but asking the teacher is the best one.

#1 is the more native way to say it. #2 would sound redundant because put 还是 before 最好 would make it lose the "is still" meaning and function as "better off" instead

Comment: I think the questioned sentence will go except for redandance.I understood that It was not impossible.谢谢。

Comment: @user9402680 I had not finish editing my answer before you accepted it, now the answer is edited. Please take a look

Comment: 最好 is not redundant-- it conveys the information that asking the teacher is the best option among all additional options the speakers haven't attempted doing.

Comment: @Frenzy Li  I wrote: "if you use 还是 as "better off" in the context"  while 最好 means "best". Which mean, the meaning of  " better off" or "best to" are too similar that you only need one or the other.

Comment: I understand your point, but I disagree with that particular part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are few previous posts that addressed the adverb order. You can have a search and take a look.

For natives, we determine the order by intuition, which is formed by using/speaking the language for many years.

Back to your examples. Your first sentence, *这个问题，最好还是问问老师吧*, is more natural and idiomatic. The second one, *这个问题，还是最好问问老师吧*，is not that natural, but if you put it into practice, especially given that you aren't a native, it's still acceptable.

Anyhow, like other languages, we have more tolerance in colloquial speech than writing.